# PhpStorm doesn't recognize class

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am instantiating my `Socket` class in `XmppClient` constructor:

```
public function __construct(Options $options, $sessionId = null)
{
    ...

    try {
        $this->socket = new Socket($options, $this->responseBuffer);
    } catch (DeadSocket $e) {
        $this->options->getLogger()->error(__METHOD__ . '::' . __LINE__ . " " . $e->getMessage());
    }

    ...
}
```

In return, when calling socket methods from other methods in `XmppClient` class, everything looks normal:

```
public function send(string $xml)
{
    $this->socket->send($xml);
}
```

However if I move the socket creation code to a separate method so that I have a constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(Options $options, $sessionId = null)
{
    ...
    $this->initSocket($options);
    ...
}
```

I am no longer getting PhpStorm to recognize that `send()` is `Socket` class method (I get a squiggle below it, can't follow the method with CMD+click)

Even though I could type hint it and resolve the issue:

```
/**
 * @var $socket Socket
 */
protected $socket;
```

I see this as unnecessary code clutter. Is there a way for PhpStorm to recognize that class from non-constructor method?

Comment: I do NOT see this as unnecessary code clutter. When I read code of my teams, this code clutter save me a lot of time. I think it's a good practice to give the class of each variable.

Comment: *"I see this as unnecessary code clutter."* It's a standard PHPDoc, you can find this in many-many libraries and frameworks; it helps IDEs/editors to understand your dynamic code. *"Is there a way for PhpStorm to recognize that class from non-constructor method?"* No, because ATM PhpStorm has such special logic/treatment for constructors only.

Comment: It is probably a discussion for itself, but for me if I have a variable called `$socket` which is a reference to class `Socket`, this is clutter. If on the other hand you have variable `$socket` which is a reference to class `SocketLogger` this is just bad design.